# Valgrind suppression file for Qt 4.6.2 and RHEL 5

Tags: qt, valgrind, rhel

I'm trying to run Valgrind 3.5.0 on RHEL 5.5 with Qt 4.6.2. It's producing loads of spurious errors and I'm wondering if anyone can share a suppressions file they've built?  When using --leak-check=full, the output reports leaks in glib, gtk, pango etc. even when I'm just running part7 of the AddressBook example. With over 25000 lines the real memory leaks are lost in the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awesome [Valgrind Suppression File Howto](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto) helped me in generating a suppression file quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I have not any suppression file with these libraries, but I suggest you to run a light test (unit test for example) with `--gen-suppressions=all` enabled, and then add-it to your run.